# The SQL query text exceeded the maximum limit of 30720 characters in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a query where I use an array with an "IN" style setup.

```
var builder = Builders<Transaction>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Eq("App", app) 
                      & builder.In("TransactionId", incomingIds);
        List<string> existingTransactions = collection
            .Find(filter)
            .Project(x => x.TransactionId)
            .ToList();
```

A while back this started to throw the error below and I had reduce my batch-size significantly to avoid the error.

Command delete failed: Errors encountered exception while executing function.

Error while querying documents
Code: SC3020
The SQL query text exceeded the maximum limit of 30720 characters.

Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.0.0.

Was this limitation a "feature" added by Microsoft at some point?

I can't seem to find any info except this feedback suggestion:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/32665819-increase-query-maximum-character-limit-for-cosmo-m

Comment: Please email AskCosmosDB@microsoft.com and they can help increase this. A workaround is to reduce/split your query into multiple ones with a smaller number of "incomingIds"

Comment: Hi & thanks! Yes, splitting it up into even smaller batches is how I've solved it so far.

Comment: Queries have always been 30kb max. We are planning to increase this significantly/remove the restriction.