# Mongoose find query with populate returns error on Azure MongoDB after query results hit 500+

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, mongoose

I'm pretty new to MongoDB, Mongoose, also Azure Environments. I'm having trouble with a specific query which worked fine. But it generates error after the expected query results is 500+. The results is the accumulated report which can have maximum 1200 records. And the results is generated from 2 collections with population. Following is my node.js/express api function that generates the results.

```
index: (req, res, next) => {
    Store.find({isChecked: true}).batchSize(1200)
    .populate('lastCheckResult').exec(function (err, stores) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return next(err);
      }
      else {
        res.locals.stores = stores;
        return next();
      }
    });
  },
```

And the following is the error from Azure Web app(node.js).

> "Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":0,"end":75279},"code":"SC3004","message":"The SQL query exceeded the maximum number of 'OR' operators. The allowed limit is 500."}]} ActivityId: 96ebe198-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/32fe74cb-f1dd-4433-bfbf-ba15991cdee1/services/d914c6a9-eb86-43d8-9108-4ee395d25345/partitions/aa7a586e-7f30-4a02-99e4-8a21d2dc8295/replicas/131759772120608879s, RequestStats: ResponseTime: 2018-07-30T10:54:11.9018240Z, StoreReadResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://10.0.0.48:14000/apps/32fe74cb-f1dd-4433-bfbf-ba15991cdee1/services/d914c6a9-eb86-43d8-9108-4ee395d25345/partitions/aa7a586e-7f30-4a02-99e4-8a21d2dc8295/replicas/131759772120608879s, LSN: 2965, GlobalCommittedLsn: 2964, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 0, IsGone: False, IsNotFound: False, IsInvalidPartition: False, RequestCharge: 1, ItemLSN: -1, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Query , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.0.0.0"

Anyone help me how to fix or workaround this kind of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The SQL query exceeded the maximum number of 'OR' operators. The
>   allowed limit is 500.

Based on your error log, I presume that you are using Cosmos DB Mongo API. In fact, CosmosDB is an independent server implementation that does not directly align with MongoDB server versions and features.

CosmosDB supports a subset of the MongoDB API and translates requests into the CosmosDB SQL equivalent. CosmosDB has some different behaviours and results. But the onus is on CosmosDB to improve their emulation of MongoDB.

I suggest you you could split the number of your query data per batch to temporarily avoid this limitation. I also searched similar case related to limitation:[The SQL query text exceeded the maximum limit of 30720 characters in Azure CosmosDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761839/the-sql-query-text-exceeded-the-maximum-limit-of-30720-characters-in-azure-cosmo).

Certainly, you could add feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to get official assistance or consider using [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/microsoft-azure/) on Azure if you'd like full MongoDB feature support.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I use Cosmos DB Mongo API. And I had to reduced to number of records in the result to workaround the problem. I'll definitely consider using MongoDB Atlas for the next project. :)